# SIM800L - No response while sending AT commands

Tags: software, at-commands, 3g

I'm new to this arduino world. I'm trying to communicate with my arduino nano and SIM800L. I read few things in the internet and found a basic code. I tried copying it and tried to work it out, but I'm not getting the response as expected. I'm posting the code which I tried:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(11, 10); // RX, TX 

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Testing SIM800L module");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Sizeof(mySerial) = "); Serial.println(sizeof(mySerial));
  Serial.println();

}

void loop() // run over and over
{

  if( mySerial.available() )
  {
    char c = mySerial.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    String Arsp = Serial.readString();

    Serial.println("Serial available");
    Serial.println(Arsp);
    mySerial.println(Arsp);
    Serial.println("Serial available end");
  }

}
```

I tried to send AT command and the output I received was:

```
Testing SIM800L module

Sizeof(mySerial) = 31

Serial available
AT
```

Serial available end

I don't get OK, which I should receive, it's returning empty.

I don't understand what's going wrong. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Have you checked the baudrate of SIM800?

Comment: Yea, it's 9600.

Comment: @AbelTom: I've updated my question. Take a look.

Comment: How are you resetting the SIM800L? A link to the SIM800L module that you're using may help, since there are many available.

Comment: @SteveG: Hi steve. All I did is, uploaded the above program to Nano. Connected my Nano to my PC using USB. Connected pin-11 of Nano to RX pin of SIM800L, pin-10 of Nano to TX pin of SIM800L. Then provided a 4V supply to SIM800L. First for few seconds, SIM800L's LED blinked continuously, later it started blinking after few seconds. I even tried connecting Nano-TX(10) to SIM800L-RX and Nano-RX(11) to Sim800L-TX, but it continuously printed garbage value. So, I interchanged as told above. What else I should do?

Comment: I'm sure you made sure the 5V of SIM800 is cnnected to 5V and not 3.3 or so, and RST to GND.

Comment: **Grinds teeth**  You did not find "a basic code.". You found some example code or a basic program.

Comment: @AbelTom As far as I remember sim800 doesn't work @ 5 V. It is some small range around 4V

Answer (score 1):

Just include '\r\n' after command AT.

For example (test the code below):

```
sim800.print("AT\r\n"); 
at_cmd_return = sim800.readString();
Serial.println(at_cmd_return);
delay(4000);
```

Att,

Answer (score -2):

Use `#include <string.h>` at the start since you can't use any string without the initialisation. Otherwise, your code should be working.

Comment: i mean use #include string.h.

Comment: Its been a while since I did any work with the arduino libraries, but my recollection is that string functions are included automatically without needing a header.